# php json array problems

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating a json array in PHP like this (it's inside a class):

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT ID,title,content FROM table WHERE ID= '".$ID."' ");
$querycount = $STH->rowCount();
if($querycount!=0):
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    while( $row = $STH->fetch()) :
        $thread[$row->ID]['title'] = $row->title;
        $thread[$row->ID]['content'] = $row->content;
    endwhile;
    $this->querycount = $querycount;
    $this->thread = json_encode($thread);
 else:
    $this->querycount = $querycount;
 endif;
```

But I seem to get "strange" decodes the other end. I cannot actually reference the array by key's;

So far it will let me do this: (Where af_threads is the class name and $key id the ID in the table query)

```
$threads = new af_threads($key,$DBH);
$threads = json_decode($threads->thread); 
foreach($threads as $key1=>$thread): 
    foreach($thread as $key2=>$val):  
        echo $key2; 
        echo $val; 
    endforeach;
    echo '<hr />';
endforeach;
```

But what it will not let me do is something like this

```
$threads[$key]['title']
```

I'm not sure why.  As the class builds i.e. with more rows etc. I will need to call specific rows in specific places. i.e. `$threads[$key]['newrow']`, `$threads[$key]['newrow2']`, and or to manipulate a row with say `substr()`; etc.

Yes I know I could just echo out an array without json, but eventually I want to add cross domain functionality with JQuery getJSON() ...

Have I got it all wrong?

Comment: How does the generated JSON look like? Have you verified it is the same as you'd expect?

Comment: My json gives me something like this (1 & 2 are the tableID's $row->ID in the array creation): stdClass Object ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [title] => this is [content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum varius urna. Donec quis turpis elit. ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [title] => that is [content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum varius urna. Donec quis turpis elit. ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `json_decode()` returns `stdClass`, modify second line with

```
$threads = json_decode($threads->thread, true)
```

and you will get an associative array and be able to reference it by keys, `$threads[$key]['title']` for example.

Comment: David - many many thanks, in the past I have always "serialized" and not played with json got it now with "true"